# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration

Tags: scala, exception, configuration, apache-spark, hbase

I want to create my first scala program using the scala example [`HBaseTest2.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/HBaseTest.scala), provided in **Sparkd 1.4.1**. The goal is to connect to HBase and do some basic stuff, such as counting rows or scan rows. However, when I tried to execute the program, I got an error. It seems that Spark couldn't find the class `HBaseConfiguration`. Assuming the we're located a the root path of my project HBaseTest2 `/usr/local/Cellar/spark/programs/HBaseTest2`. Here are some details for the exception :

**./src/main/scala/com/orange/spark/examples/HBaseTest2.scala**

```
package com.orange.spark.examples

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, HTableDescriptor, TableName}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat

import org.apache.spark._


object HBaseTest2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseTest2")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val tableName = "personal-cloud-test"

    // please ensure HBASE_CONF_DIR is on classpath of spark driver
    // e.g: set it through spark.driver.extraClassPath property
    // in spark-defaults.conf or through --driver-class-path
    // command line option of spark-submit

    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()

    // Other options for configuring scan behavior are available. More information available at
    // http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableInputFormat.html
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)

    // Initialize hBase table if necessary
    val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)
    if (!admin.isTableAvailable(tableName)) {
      val tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf(tableName))
      admin.createTable(tableDesc)
    }

    val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])

    println("hbaseRDD.count()")
    println(hBaseRDD.count())

    sc.stop()
    admin.close()
  }
}
```

**./build.sbt**
I've added dependencies in this file to ensure all classes called are included in the jar file.

```
name := "HBaseTest2"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1",
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "1.0.1.1",
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.0.1.1",
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.0.1.1",
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.0.1.1"
)
```

**Run application**

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Mincong:spark-1.4.1 minconghuang$ bin/spark-submit \
  --class "com.orange.spark.examples.HBaseTest2" \
  --master local[4] \ 
  ../programs/HBaseTest2/target/scala-2.11/hbasetest2_2.11-1.0.jar
```

**Exception**

```
15/08/18 12:06:17 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
    at com.orange.spark.examples.HBaseTest2$.main(HBaseTest2.scala:21)
    at com.orange.spark.examples.HBaseTest2.main(HBaseTest2.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 11 more
15/08/18 12:06:17 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

The problem might come from the HBase configuration as mentioned in `HBaseTest2.scala` line 16 :

> // please ensure HBASE_CONF_DIR is on classpath of spark driver
>       // e.g: set it through spark.driver.extraClassPath property
>       // in spark-defaults.conf or through --driver-class-path
>       // command line option of spark-submit

But I don't know how to configure it... I've added the `HBASE_CONF_DIR` to `CLASSPATH` in my command line. The CLASSPATH is now `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hbase-1.0.1.1/conf`. Nothing happened... T_T So what should I do to get this fixed ? I can add/delete details if needed. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```scala
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hbase-1.0.1.1/conf")
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I've just tried as you said, but it didn't work. According to [Spark configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment): In client mode, this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point. And I really doubt if `$HBASE_CONF_DIR` is a classpath. Shoudn't we add sth like `$HBASE_CONF_DIR/abc.jar` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from class-path-setting as mentioned in [HBaseTest2.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/HBaseTest.scala) line 33 :

> // please ensure HBASE_CONF_DIR is on classpath of spark driver
>   // e.g: set it through spark.driver.extraClassPath property
>   // in spark-defaults.conf or through --driver-class-path
>   // command line option of spark-submit

As I'm using a **MAC OS X**, setting is different from Linux. When I tried `echo $CLASSPATH`, it returned empty. It seems that Mac doesn't use the CLASSPATH to do the driver job.  So I need to add all jar files through spark.driver.extraClassPath in spark-defaults.conf file. My collegue did the same way in Linux. I think there's a better way to handle it elegantly, but we didn't find out. Please share if you know the answer. Thanks.

---

**Mac / Linux**
add all external jars in conf/spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath    /path/to/a.jar:/path/to/b.jar:/path/to/c.jar
```